# "title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415 error when request API from python

Tags: python, http-status-code-415

Why is the same restful api API when I use it with react and java android I don't get error 415 but when I use python requests I get an error: "title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415

```
    URL = "http://localhost:44327/api/UserOfficial/UserOfficialAuthenticate"
    def Login():
    data = {
        'username': 'hienkieu',
        'password': '197353995'
    }
    length = len(json.dumps(data))
    hearder = {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'content-Length': length
    }
    r = requests.post(URL, data, hearder)
    return r.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to do this.

```
URL = "http://localhost:44327/api/UserOfficial/UserOfficialAuthenticate"
def Login():
    data = {
        'sername': 'hienkieu',
        'password': '197353995'
    }
    data = json.dumps(data) # <<<<<<<<<////////////// Edit is here
    length = len(json.dumps(data))
    hearder = {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'host': '104.154.118.39',
        'content-Length': length
    }
    r = requests.post(URL, data, hearder)
    return r.text
```

Comment: Your are using Django_rest_framework APIs ? or you are using simple APIs?

Comment: I using simple APIs. My Android application and Frontend react still use it normally

Comment: try to remove Headers from your request... it should work. In my opinions, there is no need to pass these headers

Comment: I followed your advice. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: One biggest Solution, Use django_rest_framework.

Comment: If can not use django_rest_framework. then try to check received data type.

Comment: can i check your backend code? or just simple that function where you are handling post request in backend?

Comment: can you tell me your github user?  I will add you to my backend project for you to test.

Comment: I added you to my project.  please check your email and help me.

Comment: You are using c# language as your backend backend language?

Comment: I can help you in just Django or Javascript as backend

Comment: right.  I'm using C# to build the backend